# Livewire 3 - Disappearing Livewire Component {with single root element and no comments}

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this code in my parent component:

```
@foreach ($user->loans as $index => $loan)
    <livewire:loan-component :loanId="$loan->id" :key="'loan-'.$loan->id">
@endforeach
```

And this is the component:

```
<div class="card p-4 mt-4 position-relative">
    <div class="delete position-absolute top-0 end-0 mt-2 me-3">
        <button class="btn text-danger rounded-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loanModal{{$loanId}}" wire:click.prevent>
            <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <h5 class="fw-bold fs-6 mb-3">Program/Scheme</h5>
    <div class="table-responsive d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block d-xl-block d-xxl-block">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
            <thead>
                <th class="border">
                    Sponsor/Financial Institution
                </th>
                <th class="border">
                    Grant Amount
                </th>
                <th class="border">
                    Loan Amount
                </th>
                <th class="border">
                    Repayment Amount
                </th>
                <th class="border">
                    Loan Duration
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border">
                        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add sponsor's name" wire:model.blur='sponsor' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add grant amount" wire:model.blur='grant' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add loan amount" wire:model.blur='loan' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add repayment amount" wire:model.blur='repayment' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add loan duration" wire:model.blur='loan_duration' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="d-xs-block d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none d-xl-none d-xxl-none mb-3">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Sponsor/Financial Institution</th>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add sponsor's name" wire:model.blur='sponsor' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Grant Amount</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add grant amount" wire:model.blur='grant' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Loan Amount</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add loan amount" wire:model.blur='loan' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Repayment Amount</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add repayment amount" wire:model.blur='repayment' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Loan Duration</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control border-0" placeholder="Add loan duration" wire:model.blur='loan_duration' wire:change='saveLoan'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <label for="">Loan Statement(if available)</label>
            <label for="loan_statement_{{$loanId}}" class="border rounded px-3 w-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <i class="bi bi-paperclip fs-4 text-primary me-2"></i>
                    <div class="text-body-tertiary">PDF</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uploaded-indicator d-flex align-items-center">
                    @if ($loan_statement == null)
                        <i class="bi bi-check-circle text-body-tertiary fs-5" wire:loading.remove wire:target='loan_statement'></i>
                    @else
                        <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill text-primary fs-5" wire:loading.remove wire:target='loan_statement'></i>
                    @endif
                    <img src="{{asset('images/loading.gif')}}" alt="" style="width:30px" wire:loading wire:target='loan_statement'>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="" id="loan_statement_{{$loanId}}" class="form-control visually-hidden" wire:model.live='loan_statement' accept="application/pdf" wire:change='saveLoan'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>Credit Worthy Document/ITC</label>
            <label for="credit_worthy_document_{{$loanId}}" class="border rounded px-3 w-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <i class="bi bi-paperclip fs-4 text-primary me-2"></i>
                    <div class="text-body-tertiary">PDF</div>
                </div>
                <div class="uploaded-indicator d-flex align-items-center">
                    @if ($ITC == null)
                        <i class="bi bi-check-circle text-body-tertiary fs-5" wire:loading.remove wire:target='ITC'></i>
                    @else
                        <i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill text-primary fs-5" wire:loading.remove wire:target='ITC'></i>
                    @endif
                    <img src="{{asset('images/loading.gif')}}" alt="" style="width:30px" wire:loading wire:target='ITC'>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="" id="credit_worthy_document_{{$loanId}}" class="form-control visually-hidden" wire:model='ITC' accept="application/pdf" wire:change='saveLoan'>
        </div>
        @if ($loan_statement == null)
        <div class="col-lg-6 mt-4">
            <label for="">Reason for loan statement not available(if not attached)</label>
            <textarea name="" id="" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason" wire:model.blur='loan_statement_unavailability' wire:change='saveLoan'></textarea>
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="loanModal{{$loanId}}" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{$sponsor}} loan?</strong>  Doing so will <span class="text-danger fw-bold">remove</span> it from yout application.
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger px-5" wire:click='delete' data-bs-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-5" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My function I am calling:

```
public function addLoan() {
   $user = Auth::user();

   if ($this->loan_statement != null) {
       $loanStatement = $this->first_name . '_' . $this->last_name . "_" . str_replace(' ', '_', $this->sponsor) . "_loan_statement." . $this->loan_statement->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $this->loan_statement->storeAs('/public/loanStatements', $loanStatement);
    } else {
       $loanStatement = '';
    }

    if ($this->ITC != null) {
       $loanITC = $user->first_name . '_' . $user->last_name . "_" . str_replace(' ', '_', $this->sponsor) . "_credit_worthy_statement." . $this->ITC->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $this->ITC->storeAs('/public/creditWorthyStatements', $loanITC);
    } else {
       $loanITC = '';
    }

    Loan::create([
       'user_id' => $user->id,
       'sponsor' => $this->sponsor,
       'grant' => $this->grant,
       'loan' => $this->loan,
       'repayment' => $this->repayment,
       'loan_duration' => $this->loan_duration,
       'ITC' => $loanITC,
       'loan_statement' => $loanStatement,
       'loan_statement_unavailable' => $this->loan_statement_unavailable,
    ]);

    $this->reset();
}
```

Every time I add a new loan, all the previous components disappear from the DOM. I have tried the fixes in the documentation (key, single root element) but still not success. I am not getting any error message in my console. How can I fix this?

Comment: How is the relation of `$loans` from the `$user` model loaded on your parent component? Because this sounds like a hydration issue.